# pip3 is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, pip

I got the following error when using `pip3` in Ubuntu:

```
mt@mt:~$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
mt@mt:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip3 install face_recognition
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip3 install face_recognition
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Comment: Why are you running `pip3 install` in Python, when `pip3` is a separate command?

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to run it in an interactive Python session. It's its own command. Exit the Python shell (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and then just run the command from the standard Bash shell:

```
pip3 install --user face_recognition
```

Note, you'll need to [follow that readme](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/face_recognition) *closely*. You'll need to do some contortion to install face_recognition's dependencies.

Comment: `pip3 install --user`, preferably - do you really want to risk running random scripts as root because [they made a typo](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/4n4w2h/taking_over_17000_hosts_by_typosquatting_package/)?

Comment: @muru Using a virtualenv even more preferably. :) I just recently started using them and I am wondering why I didn't start sooner...

Comment: Yeah there are swings and roundabouts here. I'm too used to working in a virtualenv or throwaway (scripted) installs... But some things (hello *every* Python QT library) are a real pig to install  in a non-system context. Never actually played with --user before so that may not fall foul of the same issues.